# How do i update Auth0 lock logo from my React App using hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, auth0, auth0-lock

I am using auth0
`"@auth0/auth0-spa-js": "^1.6.0"` hooks for my react app.

How do i change the default logo forom auth0 in login lock?
The logo i want to change is highlited by red

[image]
I have already updated the Application Logo in dashboad, but its still not showing.

Thanks in advance :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using [Universal Login](https://auth0.com/docs/universal-login) you can go to Auth0 Dashboard > Universal Login page and turn on `Customize Login Page` toggle.

Once you have done that find the `theme` option for Auth0 Lock configuration. I should look like this

```
theme: {
        //logo:            'YOUR LOGO HERE',
        primaryColor:    colors.primary ? colors.primary : 'green'
      },
```

Uncomment the `logo` property and point to the image url for your logo. For `logo` and other customizations of Auth0 Lock please refer to official documentation [here](https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/lock/v11/configuration#logo-string-)